# Application requiring MSVCR120.DLL but not shown in Project Deployment - what unit is requiring it (if anyone knows)

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I recently completed a new project (Windows only) using Rio, IB-Lite and FastReports VCL 6 (pro). Everything works great, installed it on a number of PCs with no problems.  Created the installation packages (32 and 64 bit) based on the requirements as shown in Project Deployment.

Unfortunately, I received a note yesterday from a user, that when he tried to install on his PC, received a "Need MSVCR120.DLL" message (he was installing to a Win 8.1 64-bit PC). I was somewhat surprised by this, but knowing that the "120" in the name referred to the Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 release, I remembered I had a very old laptop which probably didn't have that installed (running XP).  Sure enough, I installed the 32-bit program, and got the error. After copying the MSVCR120.DLL and MSCVP120.DLL files to the application folder on the old PC, everything ran fine (actually, sort of amazed me). I updated the installation packages to include these files, for cases such as this.

So, my question: What is requiring this dependency (if anyone knows), and why doesn't Project Deployment pick it up?  The library units used by the project are:

```
//  Library Units used in project

// Data & FireDac
Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove, FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.DataSet,
FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.Text, FireDAC.Comp.Client, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet,
FireDAC.Comp.Script, FireDAC.Comp.ScriptCommands, FireDAC.Comp.UI,
FireDAC.DApt, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.Phys,
FireDAC.Phys.IB, FireDAC.Phys.IBBase, FireDAC.Phys.IBDef, 
FireDAC.Phys.IBLiteDef, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.SQLite,
FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteDef, FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteVDataSet, FireDAC.Stan.Async,
FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs,
FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Param,
FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.StorageJSON, FireDAC.Stan.StorageXML,
FireDAC.Stan.Util, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.VCLUI.Error, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait,

// Fast Reports VCL 6
frxChBox, frxClass, frxCross, frxDBSet, frxDCtrl, frxDesgn,
frxExportBaseDialog, frxExportCSV, frxExportDOCX, frxExportPDF, 
frxExportRTF, frxExportText, frxExportXLS, frxFDComponents, frxGradient,
frxOLE, frxRich,

// System
System.Actions, System.Classes, System.DateUtils, System.ImageList,
System.IniFiles, System.IOUtils, System.Math, System.StrUtils,
System.SysUtils, system.types, System.Variants,

//VCL
Vcl.ActnList, Vcl.BaseImageCollection, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.ComCtrls,
Vcl.Controls, Vcl.DBCtrls, Vcl.DBGrids, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
Vcl.FileCtrl, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Grids, vcl.htmlhelpviewer,
Vcl.ImageCollection, Vcl.Imaging.jpeg, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage,
Vcl.ImgList, Vcl.Mask, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ToolWin,
Vcl.VirtualImageList, Vcl.WinXCtrls,

//WinAPI
Winapi.Messages, Winapi.Windows;
```

Including the DLLs aren't the issue, more concerned how I should have known to include them in the first place

Thanks - Rick

Comment: Can try [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) a freeware utility that walks DLL dependencies. Might help in showing if some other DLL causes the attempt to load MSVCR210.DLL.

Comment: As @Brian said, DependencyWalker will help you identify what's requiring it. Also it's worth pointing out that including the DLLs directly in your install violates the MS guidelines, which say that you must use their installer to install the VC++ runtime.

Comment: My guess would be the interbase client library requiring the c++ runtime. You'll find out soon enough though...

Comment: @KenWhite, Yep - last night's "fix" was simply to get the user started. I will spend more time on the installation packages to "do it right" (once I figure that out - using Inno-Setup).

Comment: Thanks all for the pointer to Dependency Walker!  @SertacAkyuz, you are correct, it is the Interbase client library requiring these two DLLs.